# Is it possible to add multi media type to HTTP header?

Tags: spring, http-headers

I want to make a request have both JSON and file

My controller :

```
@Authorize(roles={UserType.ADMIN,UserType.SCHOOL_ADMIN})    
@RequestMapping(value="import",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public List<AddUserResponse>importUserBundle(@RequestBody AddUserRequest test,@RequestParam(value="userCsv")MultipartFile[] userCsv)
```

And got error when making a request :

> Content type
>   'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary62tvsTfonhCQ6HSl;charset=UTF-8'
>   not supported

Is there any way to make a request with both multipart/form-data and application/json media type?

Answer (score 0):

Your `AJAX` call should be like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/importUserBundle',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
       userCsv: FileToSend,
       test: JsonData
       },
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
        }
   });
```

**EDITED**

> **processData:false** Don't process the files
>
> **contentType:false** Set content type to false as jQuery will tell
>   the server its a query string request.

Look at this for more info http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax

Hope this will help